# Chrome расширения грузит процессор на 99%

Tags: google-chrome

Появилась проблема, у меня было расширение (устанавливал его через arc welder, apk файл одного приложения).

Так вот, ни с чего ни с того при запуске оно начала загружать процессор на 99 процентов.

Пробовал запускать приложение через bluestacks, там нормально.

Comment: подождем телепатов, которые угадают приложение, конфигурацию компа и цвет глаз смотрящего на монитор.

Comment: @KoVadim приложения - любой apk файл который запущен через arc welder